# How to run two rails web applications together

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am very newbie of rails. I have two rails web applications. Both of them is connected to same database. I want one of them to run separately on spesific folder. Is it possible ? How can do that ?

Thank you ...

Comment: for development or production?

Comment: If in rails 3, particularly 3.1+, it might be worth looking into turning one of them into an engine.  Rails 3+ makes engines fairly easy, 3.1+ makes them easily mountable as sub-apps.

Comment: @apneadiving I want to run both of them on production env.

Comment: Not sure I understand the problem, but can't you just use the same database.yml settings in both apps?

Comment: Agree with Andrew, I can't see any problem

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a server configuration problem than anything else. Basically, create 2 directories on your production server, one for each application.

If you're using nginx and passenger, after successfully deploying each application through capistrano, edit the nginx configuration file so that each application has its own block looking roughly like this:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  root <full_path_to_app_1>;
  server_name <DNS name for app 1>;
  passenger_enabled on;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  root <full_path_to_app_2>;
  #the rest is about the same
}
```

This way, your production server will support multiple Rails apps. The documentation on how to set up all this is extensive, so you should be able to figure the details out.